# Cannot instantiate the type ADBDataSource using axis2

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

After using Eclipse EE and Eclipse Axis2 Code Generator plugin, I got a two
operation generated java files with the same error:

```
Cannot instantiate the type ADBDataSource   ConcatRequest.java  
Cannot instantiate the type ADBDataSource   ConcatResponse.java
```

Here is the problem:

```
org.apache.axiom.om.OMDataSource dataSource = new
org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource(this,MY_QNAME);
```

This code appears in both ConcatRequest.java and ConcatResponse.java and
causes the error. I see that ADBDataSource is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

I'm totally new to Axis and I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem due to a version mismatch of `axis2-adb`. Safest way to deal with this problem is to have a look at the lib folder of the eclipse plugin (`eclipse/(dropins|plugins)/ ... .jar`). Then look for the versions of the dependecies and include them (the ones you actually need) in your build path.

Comment: Another way to find out eclipse plugin for Axis2 version: Help --> Install New Software --> Already Installed --> Plug-ins.

Answer (score 2):

i faced the same issue while generating JAVA Stubs from WSDL. Following are the steps I used to solve the issues :

1. Follow the below link to generate Stubs : https://support.pcmiler.com/en/support/solutions/articles/19000053078-java-client-axis2-code-generator-for-eclipse.

Now there is a small tweak to this link. After doing point no 10 & 11 as mentioned in the above link , only use axis2-1.7.9 to generate your stubs and when they are generated used the jars mentioned in the \axis2-1.7.9\lib in your build path.

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but I was working on a legacy project with several subprojects.
In one of those subprojects, I came across this same message. 
It also was a version problem (Maven dependencies...).

- Ctrl-Click (in Eclipse/IntelliJ) on "ADBDataSource". Which version is it? For me it was 1.5.6, but in my pom.xml there was only

```html
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
 <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
 <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

- However, this subproject had a dependency on another subproject which WAS using 1.5.6 (I found it by searching in the whole project for "1.5.6" using the Notepad++ "Search / Find in Files" menu option).
- Then in the dependency to that other project, I excluded 1.5.6 :

```html
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>anotherproject</artifactId>
  <version>version</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

- After adding the exclusion, the project did use the 1.7.4 version.